# Is there a function that can produce unique solutions for $r$, given $l$, $t$, and $c$?

Tags: functions

This is a follow up question to [How do you solve $r=\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{l+r\cdot t}{c}\right)$ for $r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654595/how-do-you-solve-r-operatornameceil-left-fraclr-cdot-tc-right-for-r)

I am trying to create a function that prints mono-spaced text to a computer console and wraps the text with a certain number of tabs. The output looks something like this,

```
    this is some t
    ext that is wr
    apped
```

or this:

```
        this is so
        me text th
        at is wrap
        ped
```

What I want to know is, given a certain string of text of length $l$, number of spaces to put before the text $t$, and maximum number of characters in a row $c$, is there a mathematical function that can produce the amount of rows $r$ the text will take up in the console?

In the examples above, such a function would work like this:

$f(l,t,c)=r$

$f(33,4,18)=3$

$f(33,8,18)=4$

I already have several other methods of printing wrapped text like this to the console without this mathematical function that involve programming loops, but I would like to see if there is a way to do it with a mathematical function.